# How to extract HTML from a database using Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Project is based on as.net mvc and i am using Razor as the view engine.

I am using LINQ2Sql classes to extract data from the database.
In a one particular column there is content with html formatting.

While extracting this data using LINQ and then putting it in a viewbag and then using it in a display view. The formatting got lost because of the fact the < brackets are converted to &lt and /&gt.

How to avoid this?

Comment: How are you rendering your display-view?

Comment: i have a repository class which will fetch the data. It will get called in my controller and assigned to a var type variable. Then this var variable is assigned to a viewbag property and then controller redirect to a view where i fetch the data from this viewbag using foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following method:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("your string")
```

For further documentation about this method, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) .

The above method is helpful *provided that* your html is stored as encoded html. Otherwise it will no be helpful. As Mathew pointed out in his comment, then you should use the following method:

```
@Html.Raw("your string")
```

Comment: I think that's a classic issue. That's why I suggested this method.

Comment: If his database already contains non-encoded html this is not of any help. He'll need `@Html.Raw(string)` to convert it to a `MvcHtmlString` and bypass the auto encoding. You might want to include that in your answer.

Comment: I am glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Render HTML directly by either wrapping it in an `MvcHtmlString` instance, or rendering it directly with `<%: myHtmlString %>`.

Comment: i think this one is applicable only for aspx engine